# Public Lightning application with multiple pages

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, lightning-apps

I need to create a 2 page 'public' application in Lightning which will be accessible to all. Basically its a search application where on the 1st page, the list of accounts will be displayed, and on clicking one of the accounts, the details will be displayed in the 2nd page. Is it possible to create such an application in Lightning?

I have created a Lightning application and have designed the 1st page, but now how can I show the details of an account in another page? If it had been a popup, then I could have easily done it.

Also in the details page, there will be a back button which will display the search results that were generated before.

Do I need to change my approach and use Lightning Communities?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have provided, a lightning community would better suit your needs. Additionally, there are OOTB components that allow users to search Object records (in your case accounts) and upon selection, they are redirected to the record detail page.

Dont try to reinvent the wheel =P

Additionally, you will be able to easily make the community "public".  I would recommend you to start taking a look at the [Communities developer guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/communities_dev.pdf).

If you encounter any setbacks during your implementation, feel free to browse the [Help and Training portal](https://help.salesforce.com/) and if you don't find any answers to your queries, feel free to open a new post here.